# help to plot Poincaré section for double pendulum

Tags: differential-equations

I am reading a book about classical mechanics. In the chapter about chaos, it gives the simplified and scaled equations for double pendulum as

$$
 \frac{d}{dt}\left[
 \begin{matrix}
 \alpha \\[3mm] l_\alpha \\[3mm] \beta \\[3mm] l_\beta
 \end{matrix}
 \right]
 =
 \left[
 \begin{matrix}
  2\frac{l_\alpha - (1+\cos\beta)l_\beta}{3-\cos 2\beta} \\[2mm]
  -2\sin\alpha - \sin(\alpha + \beta) \\[2mm]
  2\frac{-(1+\cos\beta)l_\alpha + (3+2\cos\beta)l_\beta}{3-\cos2\beta}\\[2mm]
  -\sin(\alpha+\beta) - 2\sin\beta\frac{(l_\alpha-l_\beta)l_\beta}{3-\cos2\beta} + 2\sin2\beta\frac{l_\alpha^2-2(1+\cos\beta)l_\alpha l_\beta + (3+2\cos\beta)l_\beta^2}{(3-\cos2\beta)^2}
 \end{matrix} 
  \right] 
 $$

I am going to plot the Poincaré section, which in this case is the collection of $(\beta, l_\beta)$ when $\alpha=0$ and $d\alpha/dt >0$. I follow the code found in the example of *Mathematica* for Poincaré section and write the following code

```
abc = {a'[t] == 2*(la[t] - (1 + Cos[b[t]])*lb[t])/(3 - Cos[2*b[t]]), 
       la'[t] == -2*Sin[a[t]] - Sin[a[t] + b[t]],
       b'[t] == 2*(-(1 + Cos[b[t]])*la[t] + (3 + 2*Cos[b[t]])*lb[t])/(3 - Cos[2*b[t]]),
       lb'[t] == -Sin[a[t] + b[t]] - 2*Sin[b[t]]*((la[t] - lb[t])*lb[t])/(3 - Cos[2*b[t]]) + 
                  2*Sin[2*b[t]]*(la[t]^2 - 2*(1 + Cos[b[t]])*la[t]*lb[t] + 
                  (3 + 2*Cos[b[t]])*lb[t]^2)/(3 - Cos[2*b[t]])^2};

psect[{a0_, la0_, b0_ , lb0_}] := 
      Reap[NDSolve[{abc, a[0] == a0, la[0] == la0, b[0] == b0, lb[0] == lb0, 
                   WhenEvent[a[t] == 0 && la'[t]>0, Sow[{b[t], lb[t]}]]}, {}, 
                   {t, 0, 1000},  MaxSteps -> ∞]][[-1, 1]]

abcdata = Map[psect, {{0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0}, {0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01}, 
                      {0.01, 0.01, 0.01, -0.01}}];

ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Here a is $\alpha$, b is $\beta$, la is $l_\alpha$ and lb is $l_\beta$. I don't know why, they code has two problems. First the condition "la'[t]>0" doesn't work. Secondly, even I remove the condition "&& la'[t]>0", it sill reports that error code like "NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of 0.01` in the first argument". I spent quite a long time to figure out the problem but I still cannot find out the reason.

Here is plot for the Poincaré section from the book I am reading (I redraw with image editor).
[image]

Comment: One mistake: You wrote `lb[0] = lb0` which is given away by the fact that `lb` is coloured black, as well as by Mathematica seeing a number where there should be an equation.  Use `==`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I correct that but I still don't know how to extract the section when $\alpha=0$ and $d\alpha/dt>0$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`WhenEvents[]` is a tricky beast (thanks to @Szabolcs for pointing out a better way to write the event detection part)

```
psect[{a0_, la0_, b0_, lb0_}] := 
  Reap[NDSolve[{abc, a[0] == a0, la[0] == la0, b[0] == b0, lb[0] == lb0, 
              WhenEvent[a[t] + 0*b'[t] + 0*la[t] + 0*lb[t] == 0, 
                        If[la[t] >= 0, Sow[{b[t], lb[t]}]]]}, 
              {a, la, b, lb}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
              MaxStepSize -> .0005]][[2, 1]];
ps = psect /@ Table[{0.01, 0.005, 0.01, i}, {i, -.01, .01, .00125}];
ListLinePlot[#[[FindCurvePath[#][[1]]]] & /@ ps, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This didn't work for me when I tried the same ...  When I tried to actually `Sow` `la'[t]`, I noticed that it came out evaluated ... let me paste your code ...

Comment: OK, I see the trick you did now: you included `la'` in the event part of `WhenEvent` to force its evaluation in the action part.  This is a bit confusing though.  Suppose you'd want `la'[t] >= 0` instead of `la'[t] > 0`.  How would you avoid `la[t] == 0 && a[t] != 0` being detected?  Also, do you also think that what we see is a bug?

Comment: @Szabolcs I found a lot of `WhenEvent[]` quirks like this one lately. I assume it's just immature (but useful)

Comment: This seems to give an incorrect result, because of the reason I mentioned.  Try `Sow`ing `a[t]` and `la'[t]` instead to see their values. It will detect points where `la'[t]` is zero up to a `Chop` but `la'[t]>0` is also true.   We can modify it slightly to make it work, and we don't even need the `If` part.  The point is to mention `la'[t]` in the event somewhere but make absolutely sure that it does't make a difference.  note that `WhenEvent` is `HoldAll`!  So we can do this:

Comment: `WhenEvent[a[t] + 0*la'[t] == 0 && la'[t] > 0, Sow[{whatever}]]`.  This will give a correct result and multiplying `la'[t]` by 0 ensures that it does not make a difference in the event.

Comment: @Szabolcs yep, much better. Do you mind if I edit the answer with that?

Comment: Please do!  I don't care about rep points any more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the code. I am a bit confusing with the results. Since in the book, it shows the Poincare section when the initial conditions $\alpha(0) = -\beta(0) = 1^\circ$, the curves looks the one I just added to the question. I am trying to use above code with a(0)=PI/180, b(0)=-PI/180, la(0)=0 and lb(0)=-0.01, but I didn't get the result as expect.

Comment: @user1285419 See edit please

Comment: @Szabolcs Added due credit. Sorry, I forgot to do that earlier.

Comment: Thanks belisarius. I appreciate your code. I don't know what's going, it gives something different from what shown in the book. Your update did show something similar but there is still a question. The plot should be bound and if the lb range from -0.01 to +0.01, the range for beta should limited from -0.025 to +0.025. Also, if I change the range for lb from -0.02 to 0.02, I saw some curves cross but it is said that the curves should not cross. Anyway, I thanks for your code. Maybe something wrong in the math :(

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to Szabolcs for pointing out the difference between `f` and `pred` in the form

```
WhenEvent[f == 0 && pred,...]
```

The function `f` is allowed to be either a function or its derivative that appears in the system of DEs (for example `lb'[t]`), but apparently `pred` is not.  Judging from the error messages, only values of `t`, `a[t]`, `b[t]`, `la[t]`, `lb[t]` are passed to `pred`.

The difference, I suppose, is that `lb'[t]` is not a state variable.  Only `a[t]`, `b[t]`, `la[t]`, `lb[t]` are; those, as well as `t`, are replaced by their values in `WhenEvent`.  The way around is to use the fact that the DE defines what `lb'[t]` etc. are in terms of the state variables. We can use the equation in the DE system instead of `lb'[t]`.  We'll also mark **both crossings**, where `lb'[t]` changes from negative to positive and vice versa (two `WhenEvents`), otherwise only the right half of the figure is drawn.

```
psect[{a0_, la0_, b0_, lb0_}] := 
 Reap[NDSolve[{abc, a[0] == a0, la[0] == la0, b[0] == b0, lb[0] == lb0,
     WhenEvent[a[t] == 0 && -2*Sin[a[t]] - Sin[a[t] + b[t]] < 0, Sow[{b[t], lb[t]}]],
     WhenEvent[a[t] == 0 && -2*Sin[a[t]] - Sin[a[t] + b[t]] > 0, Sow[{b[t], lb[t]}]]},
    {a[t], b[t], la[t], lb[t]}, {t, 0, 1000},
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]][[-1, 1]]

abcdata = Map[psect,
              {{0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0},
               {0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01},
               {0.01, 0.01, 0.01, -0.01}}];

ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using @belisarius' data:

```
ps = psect /@ Table[{0.01, 0.005, 0.01, i}, {i, -.01, .01, .00125}];
ListPlot[ps, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**

The dimension of the phase space is four, `{a[t], b[t], la[t], lb[t]}` and the Poincaré section `a[t] == 0` is three dimensional. What we see above is a projection onto the `{b, lb}` plane, and projections can make things appear to cross.  However we can plot the iterations of the return map in 3D.  We should `Sow[{b[t], la[t], lb[t]}]` to sow the all nontrivial coordinates of the section:

```
psect3[{a0_, la0_, b0_, lb0_}] := 
 Reap[NDSolve[{abc, a[0] == a0, la[0] == la0, b[0] == b0, lb[0] == lb0,
     WhenEvent[a[t] == 0 && -2*Sin[a[t]] - Sin[a[t] + b[t]] < 0, 
      Sow[{b[t], la[t], lb[t]}]],
     WhenEvent[a[t] == 0 && -2*Sin[a[t]] - Sin[a[t] + b[t]] > 0, 
      Sow[{b[t], la[t], lb[t]}]]},
    {a[t], b[t], la[t], lb[t]}, {t, 0, 1000},
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]][[-1, 1]]
```

This shows a 3D image from a direction that nearly matches the image above:

```
ps3 = psect3 /@ Table[{0.01, 0.01, 0.01, i}, {i, -.01, .01, .00125}];
ListPointPlot3D[ps3, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We could also show a different angle & coloring:

```
Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[{Hue[First[#2]/Length[ps], 0.8, 0.8], Point[#]} &, ps],
 ImageSize -> Medium, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I would say there is nothing wrong with `WhenEvent`.  However, the documentation might be a bit more complete.  The reason I gave for the assertion that `lb'[t]` is not a valid variable for `pred` in `WhenEvent` is not clearly stated in the docs, but the docs are long and I may not have read carefully enough.  However, it makes sense from a mathematical point of view.  The integrator/solver is not going to be keeping track of derivatives in a first-order system.  While *Mathematica* could recursively determine any order derivative from the differential equation, it is doubtful that it does.

The confusing thing is that some of the examples in the docs are of second-order equations.  For those equations, the first derivative is a state variable and it may be used in `WhenEvent`.

Comment: But if you do mention `lb'[t]` in the event part of `WhenEvent` (and not in the predicate coming after `&&`) then it does work and the value of `lb'[t]` suddenly becomes available.  (See the comments below belisarius's answer.)  This is why I thought it was a bug.  If `WhenEvent` knows that `lb'[t]` needs to be kept track of when it's mentioned in the event, it should also do it when it's mentioned in the predicate.  (I'm referring to the `WhenEvent[f==0 && pred, ...]` syntax mentioned in the docs.)  Nice colour scheme in your list plot btw ;-) and +1 for actually generating the figure.

Comment: @Szabolcs  Right.  No wonder `WhenEvent` is so confusing.  It seems clear (?) that the second argument to `&&` is a function of only `{t, a, b, la, lb}`, judging from the error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the neat code. I learn something from this also. But I just don't understand the result why there is some curves crossing while the book say it is not suppose to cross.

Comment: @user1285419  I cannot explain the image in the book. It's close to what is produced above.  Artistic license, perhaps?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the update. The plots doesn't look about the same but there are one important thing not consistent. The image I attached in the post is about the same to the book. We see that there are two small islands, corresponding to the fix points, in the top and bottom. And they are not symmetric. In your plot, the plots looks identical and symmetric in the top and bottom.

Answer (score 8):

You have one mistake: you wrote `lb[0] = lb0` instead of `lb[0] == lb0`.

Once correcting that there's still the problem with including `&& la'[t]>0`.  I don't know what causes this.  As far as I can tell, this is valid syntax (it's documented).  I would contact WRI support and ask if this is a bug or an unsupported feature ... When you get a reply, it'd be nice if you could post here.

Fortunately I found one workaround:

Add `lad[t] == la'[t]` to the equations and write the condition on `lad` instead of `la'`.  It'll work, and the results seem to be correct (as compared with a plot).

---

Here's some shorter code reproducing the same problem:

```
NDSolve[{a'[t] == b[t], b'[t] == -a[t], a[0] == 1, b[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[a[t] == 0.5 && a'[t] > 0, Sow[t]]}, 

  {a, b}, {t, 0, 10}]
```