# Problem with Poincare section

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

these are equations for some double oscillators:

$x'(t)=p, p'(t)=-x-3y, y'(t)=q, q'(t)=-y-3x$

I would like to plot the Poincare section for collection of $(y,q)$ when $x=0$ and $x'(t)>0$ (or for $(x,p)$ when $y=0$ and $y'(t)>0$). I benefited from [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/PoincareSections.html) and nice answer by Mr. belisarius [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40122/help-to-plot-poincare-section-for-double-pendulum/40139#40139) and I wrote:

```
abc = {x'[t] == p[t], p'[t] == -x[t] - y[t], y'[t] == q[t], q'[t] == -y[t] - x[t]};
psect[{x0_, p0_, y0_, q0_}] :=
Reap[NDSolve[{abc, x[0] == x0, p[0] == p0, y[0] == y0, q[0] == q0,
WhenEvent[x[t] + 0*y'[t] + 0*p[t] + 0*q[t] == 0,
If[p[t] >= 0, Sow[{y[t], q[t]}]]]}, {x, p, y, q}, {t, 0, 200},
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], MaxStepSize -> .0005]][[2, 1]];
ps = psect /@ Table[{0.01, 0.005, 0.01, i}, {i, -.01, .01, .00125}];
ListLinePlot[#[[FindCurvePath[#][[2]]]] & /@ ps, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

But I don't receive anything. I expect to obtain something like this:
[image]

Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: @belisarius Please, could you help me to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 5):

This may simply be just an error in transcribing desired system for assessment.  However, I post this to amplify Gregory Rut's answer for the coded system. Please note:

- documentation of Poincare section uses well defined non-linear system with specific initial conditons. This is somewhat different to this system and what is being tabulated.
- I am using the coupled linear system coded for and not the one in $\LaTeX$ which seems different (note the latter grows exponentially up very quickly, where as the former grow linearly ).
- this system can be solved analytically and I exploit this for illustrative purposes (noting the similar pattern to Gregory Rut).
- ideally I would have liked to place the axes labels. However, MMA10 seems to not do this well (I'd be interested in other users advice)
- I have only plotted small t range (as solutions grow).

  ```
  fun[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  DSolve[{x'[t] == p[t], p'[t] == -x[t] - y[t], y'[t] == q[t], 
  q'[t] == -y[t] - x[t], x[0] == a, y[0] == b, p[0] == c, 
  q[0] == d}, {x[t], y[t], p[t], q[t]}, t]; 
  tab =Table[{x[t], y[t], q[t]} /.First@fun[0.010, .01, 0.005, j], {j, -.01, .01, .00125}];
  ```

Plotting typical solutions with time (last entry of table):

[image]

Now, the table is a set of solutions for different initial conditions ($q(t)$). For any one solution you could section with perturbing initial condition ($q(t)$ which is y velocity) the following is an interactive example. I believe both the typical solution and the interactive approach illustrate the expected reason for small number of points: solutions leave space very quickly. I guess it gives insight as to how quickly solutions diverge with change in initial condition.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@tab[[1 ;; pl]], {t, 0, 30}, 
   PlotPoints -> 200, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{x0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> PointSize[0.02], LabelStyle -> 12, PlotStyle -> st], 
  ContourPlot3D[
   x == x0, {x, -0.06, 0.06}, {y, -0.08, 0.08}, {z, -0.08, 0.08}, 
   Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.2]}], 
  ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.06, 0.08}, {-0.06, 0.08}, {-0.08, 
     0.08}}], {st, {None, Automatic}}, {x0, -0.04, 0.04}, {pl, 
  Range[17]}, 
 Initialization :> (fun[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
    DSolve[{x'[t] == p[t], p'[t] == -x[t] - y[t], y'[t] == q[t], 
      q'[t] == -y[t] - x[t], x[0] == a, y[0] == b, p[0] == c, 
      q[0] == d}, {x[t], y[t], p[t], q[t]}, t]; 
   tab = Table[{x[t], y[t], q[t]} /. 
      First@fun[0.010, .01, 0.005, j], {j, -.01, .01, .00125}];)]
```

[image]

And similar insights are developed by just looking at x-y plane (with time) for the various initial conditions:

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[ParametricPlot[Evaluate@tab[[All, {1, 2}]], {t, 0, j}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.1}], {j, 1, 20}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: @Suzanne I hope this is helpful..we all learn a lot from playing around...others may have better advice and insights.

Comment: But only a question, if I want to plot Poincare section for specified initial condition like the one in Documentation, what should I do?

Comment: Could you add also the Poincare section plot for some specific initial values (as you wish), in your answer?

Comment: Actually I am looking for shapes similar to Documentation.

Comment: @GregoryRut my sincerest apologies for incorrectly citing your name! Thank you for correcting!

Comment: @Suzanne I suggest you start by playing with your own code with one initial condition and noting the comments of Gregory Rut...just look at output, plot it etc. I have to help my partner with chores at the moment. Others may give you better advice also. Try for yourself...if you get stuck in a major way you can post a question with your new deliberations.

Comment: @ubpdqn Not a problem:-).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need to filter your results and select only numbers (some of points were not evaluated correctly)

```
sps = Flatten[Select[ps, NumberQ[#[[1, 1]]] &], 1];
```

Now the plot should be ok (note that there are very few points, you'd have to increase their number in order to get a better picture).

```
ListLinePlot[#[[FindCurvePath[#][[1]]]] &@sps, Mesh -> All, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

There's a small modification in your code needed: '/@'->'@'. '/@' is the same as Map whereas '@' calls an argument for a function, for instance Sin[x] is the same as Sin@x.