# The Poincaré Sections of Yang-Mills-Higgs System

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

In the papers [Quantum Chaos in a Yang-Mills-Higgs](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217732397001503) System and [DIFFERENT FACETS OF CHAOS IN QUANTUM MECHANICS](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217979299002447), the authors have plotted three Poincaré sections for different values of `v`.

[image]

I have been trying to reproduce these sections; however, they are not coming exactly. The following is my code, which I borrowed from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241621/84456).

Hamiltonian is given by

```
H[px_, py_, x_, y_] := 1/2 (px^2 + py^2) + g^2*v^2*(x^2 + y^2) + 1/2*g^2*x^2*y^2
```

Values of parameters

```
   g = 1; v = 1.0(*1.1*)(*1.2*);
```

Hamiltonian EOMs

```
{a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[H[px[t], py[t], x[t], y[t]], px[t]], 
D[H[px[t], py[t], x[t], y[t]], py[t]], 
-D[H[px[t], py[t], x[t], y[t]], x[t]], 
-D[H[px[t], py[t], x[t], y[t]], y[t]]}

n = 140;
list = Range[n];
For[i = 1;, i < n + 1, i++, 
 ics = {Random[Real, {-0.55, 0.55}], Random[Real, {-0.45, 0.45}], 
   Random[Real, {-0.44, 0.9}], Random[Real, {-0.17, 0.9}]};
 inisol = Solve[H[ini, ics[[4]], ics[[1]], ics[[2]]] == 0.866, ini];
 inival = ini /. inisol;
 ics = {ics[[1]], ics[[2]], inival[[2]], ics[[4]]};
 TimeMin = 0;
 TimeMax = 1000;
 Section = 
  Reap[NDSolve[{x'[t] == a1, px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, py'[t] == d1, 
      x[0] == ics[[1]], y[0] == ics[[2]], px[0] == ics[[3]], 
      py[0] == ics[[4]]}, {x[t], y[t], px[t], py[t]}, {t, TimeMin, 
      TimeMax}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
     Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> x[t], 
       "EventAction" :> Sow[{y[t], py[t]}]}]][[2]];
 list[[i]] = 
  ListPlot[Transpose[Table[Section, {j, Length[Section]}]][[1]][[1]], 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[Random[], Random[], Random[]], 
     AbsolutePointSize[0.5]}]]

Show[list, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[White, Small], 
 Background -> GrayLevel[0.1]]
```

[image]

#### [Another Method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250305/84456)

With this code, I get a different result

```
     With[{icv = {{0, 0.4082401254164024`, 0, 0}, {0, 0.24008038662195985`, -0.15316368171208566`, 0.28838672839135326`}, {0, 0.24352018790129148`,         0.09848498536170303`, 0.3135210500944904`}, {0, 0.20788819727584018`, 0.18687849877360435`, 
0.3047456328865395`}, {0, 0.11124773284074371`, 0.24234454959281115`, 0.32410152798705066`}, {0, 0.09612790055948518`, 0.2562151235263743`,        0.32091473672760257`}, {0, 0.14504873906640348`, 0.2433184249171519`, 0.3098719090788399`}, {0, 0.21466692008332666`, 0.21341797098009158`, 0.2855018063099425`}, {0, 0.2242200636897092`,  0.21057030870037158`, 0.27976766448196655`}, {0,        0.3683386516212832`, 0.18778901046261137`, 0.011696534024095057`}, {0, 0.3451153373835715`,  0.23762310035771178`, 0.005962392196119196`}, {0, 0.33504538978074816`, 0.256132905175892`, 0.0016617858251372995`}, {0, 0.37097564355830726`, -0.03575247849541091`,        0.1665183633794433`}, {0, 0.37507484064199426`, -0.06280527015275122`, 0.14788240243852177`}, {0, 0.3774580162329546`, -0.08416273725065143`, 0.12924644149760023`}, {0, 0.3779249463635693`, -0.09982487978911159`, 0.11491108692766056`}, {0, 0.3818158505457779`, -0.10979169776813169`, 
0.08910744870176919`}, {0, 0.3850735819245613`, -0.11406319118771174`, 
0.06617088138986574`}, {0, 0.3571135001050445`, -0.02151416709681081`, 
0.1966226079763166`}, {0, 0.3537329768656702`, -0.0015805311387706023`, 
0.20379028526128642`}}}, 

     psection = 
       Reap[Table[
          NDSolve[{x'[t] == px[t], 
            px'[t] == -(2 g^2 v^2 x[t] + g^2 x[t] y[t]^2), y'[t] == py[t],
             py'[t] == -(2 g^2 v^2 y[t] + g^2 x[t]^2 y[t]), 
            x[0] == Part[icv[[i]], 1], px[0] == Part[icv[[i]], 2], 
            y[0] == Part[icv[[i]], 3], py[0] == Part[icv[[i]], 4]}, {x, 
            px, y, py}, {t, 0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
           Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> x[t], 
             "EventAction" :> Sow[{y[t], py[t]}]}], {i, 1, 
           Length[icv]}]][[2]];]


ListPlot[psection, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
 FrameLabel -> {{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(y\)]\)", None}, {"y", 
    "YMH system"}}, RotateLabel -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Text["E=10", {0.3, 0.4}]}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

I think there is a problem in defining the energy surface.

Comment: I cannot find the correct plots you show in any of the two papers you link ...

Comment: @Domen .. Please see this link https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1142/S0217732397001503 or this  https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217979299002447

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: (1) Look at the range of $q_2$ on the original plots, it spans $-3\lesssim q_2 \lesssim 3$. Yet, you sample $q_2$ only from `{-0.45, 0.45}`. Increase this range (also for $p_2$). (2) You look at $E=0.866$ (why?), when the original plots are for $E=10$. After fixing (1) and (2), you should get [the correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAz1n.png).

Comment: Could you share your code, please? I'm getting imaginary numbers when I do the necessary corrections as you suggest. This was the initial reason for taking them as such

Comment: yes I also get these errors (but the plot is shown nevertheless). It just means that for some combination of initial parameters, you cannot find the last one (with `Solve`) such that the energy is what you want. You can just discard these, or, for example, choose only two initial values ($y$ and $p_y$), then calculate the relationship between the other two such that the total energy is satisfied, then pick random one satisfying the condition.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because there was already a previous answer, and the person who asked the question just had doubts about that previous answer. However, the answers that arose from that doubt may be useful to other users, so the question should only be reopened if someone wishes to add something substantial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm currently co-developing an interactive tool for extracting Poincaré sections from Hamiltonian systems. I've got a preliminary version up and running, so feel free to use it. It's available on the **Wolfram Function Repository** as [ClickPoincarePlot2D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/). For your particular problem, the initial Poincaré section with $v=1$, $g=1$, and energy $E=10$ would be as follows:

```
H := Function[{S}, 1/2 (S[[2]]^2 + S[[4]]^2) + S[[1]]^2 + S[[3]]^2 + 1/2*S[[1]]^2*S[[3]]^2]

hameqns = {x'[t] == px[t], px'[t] == -(2 x[t] + x[t]*y[t]^2), 
           y'[t] == py[t], py'[t] == -(2 y[t] + x[t]^2*y[t])};

style = {PlotStyle -> {{AbsolutePointSize[1], GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.4]}}, 
         AspectRatio -> 1, PlotHighlighting -> None};
(*Omit the PlotHighlighting option if you're using a version prior to 13.3.*)

ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"][hameqns, H, 10, t, 1000, x[t], {y[t], py[t]}, style]
```

The output with the Poincaré section looks as follows:

[image]

I'll be continuing the development of this tool to address its limitations and will be adding features such as zooming into specific chaotic regions, allowing users to click on stability islands and display additional orbits. The advantage of this tool is its reduced resource consumption compared to the other code I provided in response to a different question about Poincaré sections.

You can supplement this tool with the Wolfram Community post titled [Plot Poincare Section of a given Hamiltonian](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366589):

```
PoincareSections[eqns_?VectorQ, depvars_?VectorQ, cross_, 
   retrievesec_?VectorQ, icv : {__?NumericQ}, tmax_Integer?Positive] /;
   Length[retrievesec] == 2 && Length[icv] == 4 := 
 Module[{vars, time}, 
  time = Times @@ Variables@Level[depvars, {-1}];
  vars = Head /@ depvars;
  Reap[NDSolve[
     Join @@ {eqns, 
       Thread[Through[vars[0]] == icv], {WhenEvent[cross, 
         Sow[retrievesec, "LocationMethod" -> "EvenLocator"]]}}, 
     vars, {time, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
     MaxStepSize -> 0.1]][[-1, 1]]]

PoincareSections[eqns_?VectorQ, depvars_?VectorQ, cross_, 
  retrievesec_?VectorQ, icv_?MatrixQ, tmax_Integer?Positive] := 
 Map[PoincareSections[eqns, depvars, cross, retrievesec, #, tmax] &, icv]
```

Next, I provide the initial conditions obtained with the interactive routine:

```
    icvals = {{0, 4.462528320177665`, 0.17303856765541714`, 
    0.16110958947199644`}, {0, 4.467736758629249`, 
    0.06879141200183614`, 0.1728112810629193`}, {0, 
    4.4629142781672035`, 0.08539567409649612`, 
    0.2604060356875785`}, {0, 4.457078219133263`, 
    0.09093042812804947`, 0.34339054006883457`}, {0, 
    4.44273956486575`, 0.11306944425426274`, 
    0.48630829761433114`}, {0, 4.432274545806214`, 
    0.1094320279123828`, 0.5753187057034409`}, {0, 4.422434117182368`,
     0.10295229672798317`, 0.6487512068414824`}, {0, 
    4.4126874534322456`, 0.11523870068793313`, 
    0.7082580899990921`}, {0, 4.401848022481288`, 
    0.12845252714010807`, 0.768592143805943`}, {0, 4.388180737932256`,
     0.14463303584951864`, 0.8378737262393601`}, {0, 
    4.372830596551317`, 0.16618755584494688`, 
    0.9072573870899112`}, {0, 4.354667994170191`, 
    0.18369170535991586`, 0.9845716709888115`}, {0, 
    4.335255458734564`, 0.20905045373732956`, 1.057428921061173`}, {0,
     4.381078248441183`, 0.4893283115828355`, 
    0.5720742853882897`}, {0, 4.311513492521181`, 0.2385748806574618`,
     1.1388658641149816`}, {0, 4.280339885860469`, 
    0.09636574678509191`, 1.2884555666398008`}, {0, 
    4.255797192593596`, 0.09053334214390507`, 
    1.3681365733847572`}, {0, 4.283226359375878`, -0.46353021338614`, 
    1.1064589630456512`}, {0, 4.3331024584312`, -0.6526232829598253`, 
    0.6102366637747763`}, {0, 
    4.042356859930489`, -0.09604607887886041`, 
    1.9081145978260585`}, {0, 2.122007161924683`, 
    0.08359063563407387`, 3.934858423883753`}, {0, 
    3.6138627754729127`, -1.2673396781350363`, 
    1.9307242476595103`}, {0, 
    3.5047138061488123`, -1.3987836406681824`, 
    1.9503306873933028`}, {0, 
    3.263100249458284`, -1.3390363849712978`, 
    2.4012788012705393`}, {0, 
    3.3213488705931584`, -1.2075924224381516`, 
    2.460098120471918`}, {0, 3.460895201964421`, -0.9925023019293671`,
     2.460098120471918`}, {0, 
    2.874602524936952`, -1.2075924224381516`, 2.969865553550533`}, {0,
     3.038063255679484`, -1.016401204208121`, 2.95025911381674`}, {0, 
    3.5631421293932606`, 0.47728018821399454`, 
    2.6169496383422612`}, {0, 
    3.1217459031207135`, -0.6937660234449439`, 
    3.0482913124857043`}, {0, 
    3.1145655514289583`, -0.27553523356675136`, 
    3.1855363906222545`}, {0, 
    1.449807234660935`, -1.9843067464976518`, 3.165929950888462`}, {0,
     2.0900579174201654`, -2.79568021014104`, \
-0.0014923407056293622`}, {0, 
    1.832519509623928`, -2.8844681909476537`, 
    0.03948110522791894`}, {0, 1.503596035819526`, 2.976819841668624`,
     0.12761748141920554`}, {0, 
    3.5415459321081486`, -0.8960177933209614`, 
    2.4190404376266006`}, {0, 
    3.130688321590937`, -0.07791485738605086`, 
    3.191653048664773`}, {0, 3.5390581462779105`, 0.8440741656517057`,
     2.4597042592601888`}, {0, 
    2.248738996441609`, -2.5581951869664943`, 1.361781075153312`}, {0,
     2.4662518446386414`, 
    2.5711803637365174`, -0.8340652930604416`}, {0, 
    2.4242287391373676`, 
    2.558194602848661`, -1.0170524904115879`}, {0, 2.110487349745546`,
     2.5711803637365174`, 1.524436361687664`}, {0, 2.351295468570382`,
     2.5711803637365174`, 1.1177981453517838`}, {0, 
    2.6184146448394854`, 
    2.519237320185094`, -0.6714100065260895`}, {0, 
    2.8320631190315435`, 2.4413227548579597`, 
    0.24352598022964114`}, {0, 4.177374473484878`, 
    0.2856864474739096`, 1.544768272504458`}, {0, 
    4.172899517751086`, -0.064929096498195`, 1.60576400495484`}, {0, 
    3.8439427761413656`, -0.9869181195359515`, -1.8099970122665545`}, \
{0, 3.927220540238002`, -1.1167757284145088`, 1.443108718420488`}, {0,
     2.805662794441176`, 1.7141201451380388`, 2.500368080893777`}, {0,
     3.513796576017365`, -1.4673912723866134`, 
    1.8294150239395743`}, {0, 3.160908672942136`, -1.207676054629499`,
     2.6630233674281274`}, {0, 
    4.290890526341124`, -0.8570605106573943`, 
    0.34518553431360965`}, {0, 
    4.241737814626106`, -0.14284366182532926`, 
    1.4024448967868983`}, {0, 1.2944984720466737`, 
    3.0256819948114675`, 0.12153451532887552`}, {0, 
    0.9972003079434875`, 3.0821237104495274`, 
    0.0813536281126289`}, {0, 
    1.924047846028568`, -2.8439473819482592`, 
    0.3492369734322397`}, {0, 
    2.240082902959127`, -2.7366286067454566`, 
    0.06128886811690352`}, {0, 2.1940388127188575`, 
    2.750043775497823`, 0.24639836439104817`}};
```

Now we use the PoincareSections routine with the above initial conditions:

```
hameqns = {x'[t] == px[t], px'[t] == -(2 x[t] + x[t]*y[t]^2), 
           y'[t] == py[t], py'[t] == -(2 y[t] + x[t]^2*y[t])};
states = {x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]};
cross = x[t];
retrievesec = {y[t], py[t]};

ListPlot[PoincareSections[hameqns, states, cross, retrievesec, icvals, 3000],
PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[0.05]}, Axes -> False, 
Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[White, Medium], 
Background -> GrayLevel[0], ImageSize -> Full]
```

The Poincaré section of Yang-Mills-Higgs System for $v=1$, $g=1$, and $E=10$:

[image]

Another approach using `ClickPane`:

```
YMHSection[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}, {v_, g_}, e_, tmax_] := 
 Block[{dx0, x, px, y, py},
  dx0 = Sqrt[2*e - py0^2 - 2*g^2*v^2*x0^2 - 2*g^2*v^2*y0^2 - g^2*x0^2*y0^2];
  If[Head[N[dx0]] === Complex, Nothing,
   If[# == {}, {}, First[#]] &@Last[Reap[NDSolve[{
        x'[t] == px[t],
        px'[t] == -(2 g^2*v^2* x[t] + g^2 x[t]* y[t]^2),
        y'[t] == py[t],
        py'[t] == -(2 g^2*v^2*y[t] + g^2 x[t]^2*y[t]),
        x[0] == x0,
        px[0] == dx0,
        y[0] == y0,
        py[0] == py0,
        WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, 
         Sow[{y[t], py[t]}, "LocationMethod" -> "EvenLocator"]]
        },
       {x, px, y, py}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
       MaxStepSize -> 0.1
       ]]]]]
```

Poincaré sections considering $v=1$, $g=1$ and $E=10$:

```
style = {PlotStyle -> {{AbsolutePointSize[1], GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.4]}}, 
         AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 420};
(*Omit the PlotHighlighting option if you're using a version prior to 13.3.*)

DynamicModule[{f = {}},
 Column[{Dynamic[
    MatrixForm@{MousePosition["Graphics", "Mouse not in graphics!"]}],
        Row[{ClickPane[
          Dynamic@ListPlot[f, 
            style], (AppendTo[f, 
             YMHSection[{0, 0, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, {1, 1}, 10, 2000]]) &], 
         Button[Style["Copy orbit list", 12], 
          CopyToClipboard[Iconize[f, "Orbit list"]], 
          ImageSize -> Automatic, Alignment -> Center, 
          Appearance -> {"Palette", "Pressed"}]}, "  "]}, 
      Alignment -> Center]]
```

[image]

I hope this is helpful and that you can plot some excellent Poincaré sections.

Comment: It's wonderful. Thank you for sharing. However, I'm using `Mathematica 12.0` and it has some compatibility issues, I guess. Error : "PlotHighlighting::shdw: Symbol PlotHighlighting appears in multiple contexts {System`,Global`}; definitions in context System` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions."

Comment: Don't worry, I'll set up a more hands-on interactive version for your issue using `ClickPane`.`ClickPane` is also available in the version you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much :) .

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can omit the `PlotHighlighting` option, as it's not available in your version. This way, you can use the `ClickPoincarePlot2D` resource function without issues and the other version using `ClickPane`. See the update, please! :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López It is a nice tool (+1). How you compute "displaying initial values" at fixed  Hamiltonian?  In your example there are only zeroes in the first column.

Comment: The column of zeros arises from the way I implemented `WhenEvent` in `NDSolve`. The computation continues from the choice of the cutting plane (an associated variable), the points to retrieve on the cut (two associated variables), and the remaining variable gets updated during the computation of the initial conditions. These initial conditions are tied to the chosen energy level. The routine is limited to two-degree-of-freedom systems. I hope to collaborate with a fellow community member in the future to develop a package for this topic. Thanks for your comment, @AlexTrounev! :-)

Comment: In "ClickPoincarePlot2D", To get colourful diagrams for individual sections,  `style = {PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[1], RGBColor[Random[], Random[], Random[]]}, AspectRatio -> 1, ClickPane -> None}`. However, in your edited code, I'm unable to do so. Could you please help me out with that? and I've exported the `Sections` to a .dat file using `Export["YMH.dat", Flatten[Sections, 1]]`. However, I'm unable to get the multicolour plot as previously. In the 2nd case, I'm using: `ColorFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y}, Hue[RandomReal[]](*RGBColor[RandomReal[],
  RandomReal[],RandomReal[]]*)]`

Comment: @E.Chan-López Please see update to my post how to compute initial data with using `NMinimize`.

Answer (score 10):

If we take `icv` from your second example and define Hamiltonian as

```
H0[{x_, px_, y_, py_}] := 
 1/2 (px^2 + py^2) + g^2*v^2*(x^2 + y^2) + 1/2*g^2*x^2*y^2;
```

then we have for energy levels

```
Map[H0, icv]

(*{0.08333, 0.0938619, 0.0884981, 0.102967, 0.11744, 0.12176, 0.117734, \
0.109344, 0.108612, 0.10317, 0.116035, 0.121733, 0.0839539, \
0.0852197, 0.086673, 0.0879809, 0.088916, 0.0893405, 0.0835581, \
0.0833312}*)
```

Therefore in the first example you used $H=0.866$ while in the second example $0.08333\le H \le 0.12176$. Also initial data in the first example are not same as in the second. Please, note, that in the second example we can use `icv` and `-icv` as well as follows

```
g = 1; v = 1.0(*1.1*)(*1.2*); H = 
 1/2 (px[t]^2 + py[t]^2) + g^2*v^2*(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2) + 
  1/2*g^2*x[t]^2*y[t]^2; {a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[H, px[t]], 
  D[H, py[t]], -D[H, x[t]], -D[H, y[t]]}; abcd = {x'[t] == a1, 
  px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, py'[t] == d1};

psect[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}] := 
  Reap[NDSolve[{abcd, x[0] == x0 + 10^-10, y[0] == y0, px[0] == px0, 
      py[0] == py0, WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, Sow[{y[t], py[t]}]]}, {}, {t,
       0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]][[-1, 1]];

icv = {{0, 0.4082401254164024`, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0.24008038662195985`, -0.15316368171208566`, 
   0.28838672839135326`}, {0, 0.24352018790129148`, 
   0.09848498536170303`, 0.3135210500944904`}, {0, 
   0.20788819727584018`, 0.18687849877360435`, 
   0.3047456328865395`}, {0, 0.11124773284074371`, 
   0.24234454959281115`, 0.32410152798705066`}, {0, 
   0.09612790055948518`, 0.2562151235263743`, 
   0.32091473672760257`}, {0, 0.14504873906640348`, 
   0.2433184249171519`, 0.3098719090788399`}, {0, 
   0.21466692008332666`, 0.21341797098009158`, 
   0.2855018063099425`}, {0, 0.2242200636897092`, 
   0.21057030870037158`, 0.27976766448196655`}, {0, 
   0.3683386516212832`, 0.18778901046261137`, 
   0.011696534024095057`}, {0, 0.3451153373835715`, 
   0.23762310035771178`, 0.005962392196119196`}, {0, 
   0.33504538978074816`, 0.256132905175892`, 
   0.0016617858251372995`}, {0, 
   0.37097564355830726`, -0.03575247849541091`, 
   0.1665183633794433`}, {0, 
   0.37507484064199426`, -0.06280527015275122`, 
   0.14788240243852177`}, {0, 
   0.3774580162329546`, -0.08416273725065143`, 
   0.12924644149760023`}, {0, 
   0.3779249463635693`, -0.09982487978911159`, 
   0.11491108692766056`}, {0, 
   0.3818158505457779`, -0.10979169776813169`, 
   0.08910744870176919`}, {0, 
   0.3850735819245613`, -0.11406319118771174`, 
   0.06617088138986574`}, {0, 
   0.3571135001050445`, -0.02151416709681081`, 
   0.1966226079763166`}, {0, 
   0.3537329768656702`, -0.0015805311387706023`, 
   0.20379028526128642`}}; iniv = Join[icv, -icv];

abcdata = Map[psect, iniv];
```

Visualization

```
ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Medium, Background -> GrayLevel[0.1], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1**.To compute initial data at fixed Hamiltonian `H=E0` we can use `NMinimize` as follows

```
g = v = 1; 
h[x_, px_, y_, py_] := 
 1/2 (px^2 + py^2) + g^2*v^2*(x^2 + y^2) + 1/2*g^2*x^2*y^2;

inivalues[E0_, n_, pxmin_, pxmax_] := 
  Module[{x, px, X, y, P, py, Y}, px = RandomReal[{pxmin, pxmax}, n]; 
   X = Table[0, {n}]; Y = Table[0, {n}]; P = Table[0, {n}]; 
   Do[{X[[i]], P[[i]], Y[[i]]} = {x, py, y} /. 
       NMinimize[(h[x, px[[i]], y, py] - E0)^2, {x, py, y}][[2]];, {i,
      n}]; Transpose[{X, px, Y, P}]];
```

In a case of `H=10, n=20` we have, for example,

```
iniv = inivalues[10, 20, -.5, .5]
```

Mapping Hamiltonian in the form `H0` we can check that

```
Map[H0, iniv]

(*Out[]= {10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.}*)
```

Finally we compute section data and plot

```
abcdata = Map[psect, iniv];

ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Large, Background -> GrayLevel[0.05], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: (+1) This is excellent, @AlexTrounev! Utilizing `NMinimize` is the most intelligent approach for computing the initial conditions constrained by the energy level restriction. This mitigates numerous issues within a non-interactive routine and is highly likely to, when suitably adapted to an interactive routine, address some of the challenges I observe with `NSolve` in more complex systems.

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thank you. Please note, that `NMinimize` is very effective in a case of convex functions like Hamiltonian discussed above.

Comment: What you did gives me ideas to improve the routine. Thanks,  @AlexTrounev! I'll happily cite this post and what you did in the next version of the routine. I hope collaboration is possible.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad this is useful for you.

Comment: I managed to create a compatible structure for the approach you shared with me where you use `NMinimize`. I'm thinking about integrating it into the interactive routine. Would you be interested in collaborating on an article about this? We could document the feature and perhaps delve into a couple more complex examples. Additionally, I have a zoom function to click and draw orbits in the magnified region. With these additions, our routine could be super solid.