# Poincaré section of the particle motion near the black hole horizon

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, physics, sow-reap

I am trying to recreate the Poincaré sections given in Figure 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.06070.pdf).
[image: poincare-sections]

For this purpose, I use the following two methods:

**Method1: Using [ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/)**

```
    f = 2  k  x[t];

lagrangian = -Sqrt[f - x'[t]^2/f - y'[t]^2] - \[Omega]^2/
    2  ((x[t] - xc)^2 + y[t]^2);

px1 = D[lagrangian, x'[t]]

py1 = D[lagrangian, y'[t]]

testham = (px1  x'[t] + py1  y'[t]) - lagrangian

k = 1/2; \[Omega] = 10; xc = 1;

hamiltonian[x_, px_, y_, py_] = 
  testham /. x[t] -> x /. x'[t] -> px /. y[t] -> y /. y'[t] -> py;


H := Function[{S}, (2  k  S[[1]])/Sqrt[
   2  k  S[[1]] - S[[2]]^2/(2  k  S[[1]]) - S[[4]]^2] + 
   1/2  (S[[1]]^2 + S[[3]]^2 - 2  S[[1]]  xc + xc^2)  \[Omega]^2]
    
    {a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[hamiltonian[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], px[t]], 
      D[hamiltonian[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], 
       py[t]], -D[hamiltonian[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], x[t]], -D[
        hamiltonian[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], y[t]]}; abcd = {x'[t] == 
       a1, px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, py'[t] == d1};
    
    cross = y[t]; recover = {x[t], px[t]};
    
    ResourceFunction[
      "ClickPoincarePlot2D"][abcd, H, 15, t, 10000, cross, recover, \
    {PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1], AspectRatio -> 1, 
      PlotHighlighting -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-20, 20}}}]
```

**Method2: Using algorithm of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290235/78049) by @Alex Trounev**

```
psect[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}] := 
 Reap[NDSolve[{abcd, x[0] == x0 + 10^-10, y[0] == y0, px[0] == px0, 
     py[0] == py0, WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, Sow[{y[t], py[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 
     0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]][[-1, 1]]

inivalues[E0_, n_, pxmin_, pxmax_] := 
  Module[{x, px, X, y, P, py, Y}, px = RandomReal[{pxmin, pxmax}, n];
   X = Table[0, {n}]; Y = Table[0, {n}]; P = Table[0, {n}];
   Do[{X[[i]], P[[i]], Y[[i]]} = {x, py, y} /. 
       NMinimize[(hamiltonian[x, px[[i]], y, py] - E0)^2, {x, py, 
          y}][[2]];, {i, n}]; Transpose[{X, px, Y, P}]];

iniv = inivalues[15, 100, -0.1, 0.1];

H0[{x_, px_, y_, py_}] = -Sqrt[f - px^2/f - py^2] - \[Omega]^2/
    2 ((x - xc)^2 + y^2) + px^2 + py^2;

abcdata = Map[psect, iniv];

ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Large, Background -> White, 
 Frame -> True]
```

I tried to alter the `cross` and `recover` variables in both methods but to no avail! The first method gives me an empty plot while the second one provides me with errors!

Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Comment: ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"] des not work for me. Even the examples are not working. MMA version 14

Comment: The examples are working on MMA version 13. It is developed by @E. Chan-López, who is also a regular user here, he told about his tool in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290237/78049

Comment: I'm working on an update and solving a significant issue that I observed together with Alex Trounev in order to generalize the routine so that it can be applied to more complicated systems. I estimate that I will be able to send an update by the end of February.  I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Suddenly it stopped working for my MMA version 13 as well! Seems like they are working on it. But what about the second method by @Alex Trounev ? Why am I getting errors for that?

Comment: @DanielHuber In version 13.3, which is what I have, the code works, but I appreciate that you mention that in version 14 it is not working. I will update to version 14 to ship the update.

Comment: @codebpr I'm going to make an interactive version using `ClickPane` and post it as an answer. Once I have updated the resource function and the new version is accepted in WFR, then I will repost your example using the resource function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To detect more islands, it is better to use the interactive method. Here, I provide an example with the result for the case in which the energy is equal to 40.

```
PoincareSections[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}, e_, tmax_] := 
 Block[{pdy0, x, px, y, py},
  pdy0 = 
   Sqrt[2500 + e^2 - 100*e*(-1 + x0)^2 + 
      x0*(-10001 - px0^2*x0 + 2500*x0*(6 + (-4 + x0)*x0))]/Sqrt[x0];
  If[Head[N[pdy0]] === Complex, Nothing,
   If[# == {}, {}, First[#]] &@Last[Reap[NDSolve[{
        x'[t] == px[t] x[t] Sqrt[x[t]/(1 + py[t]^2 + px[t]^2 x[t])],
        px'[t] == 
         100 - 100 x[t] - 
          px[t]^2 Sqrt[x[t]/(
           1 + py[t]^2 + px[t]^2 x[t])] - ((1 + py[t]^2) Sqrt[x[t]/(
           1 + py[t]^2 + px[t]^2 x[t])])/(2 x[t]),
        y'[t] == py[t] Sqrt[x[t]/(1 + py[t]^2 + px[t]^2 x[t])],
        py'[t] == -100 y[t],
        x[0] == x0,
        px[0] == px0,
        y[0] == y0,
        py[0] == pdy0,
        WhenEvent[y[t], 
         Sow[{x[t], px[t]}, "LocationMethod" -> "EvenLocator"]]
        },
       {x, px, y, py}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
       MaxStepSize -> 0.1
       ]]]]]
```

Next, use the code with `ClickPane` found at: [The Poincaré Sections of Yang-Mills-Higgs System](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290227/the-poincar%C3%A9-sections-of-yang-mills-higgs-system/290237#290237):

```
    style = {PlotStyle -> {{AbsolutePointSize[1], GrayLevel[0], 
             Opacity[0.4]}}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 420};
(*Omit the PlotHighlighting option if you're using a version prior to 13.3.*)

    DynamicModule[{f = {}}, 
     Column[{Dynamic[
        MatrixForm@{MousePosition["Graphics", "Mouse not in graphics!"]}],
        Row[{ClickPane[
          Dynamic@ListPlot[f, 
            style], (AppendTo[f, 
             PoincareSections[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0, 0}, 40, 3000]]) &], 
         Button[Style["Copy orbit list", 12], 
          CopyToClipboard[Iconize[f, "Orbit list"]], 
          ImageSize -> Automatic, Alignment -> Center, 
          Appearance -> {"Palette", "Pressed"}]}, "  "]}, 
      Alignment -> Center]]
```

The Poincaré section plot looks like this:

```
style ={PlotStyle -> {{Black, Opacity[0.5], PointSize[0.002]}}, ImageSize -> Large};

ListPlot["Orbit list", style]
```

[image]

Note that you can copy the list of sections by clicking on the button that says `Copy orbit list`. Afterward, you can save your generated image in PNG format.

[image]

Interactively:

[image]

The plots of the Poincaré sections for energies 15 and 49.5 respectively look like this:
[image]

[image]

To export your images with high quality, I recommend the following post: [Obtaining better quality in ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/obtaining-better-quality-in-listplot).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution (+1).

Comment: @E.Chan-López thank you for the interactive method. Just a small question, what does `pdy0` denote in your code? Have you solved for the Hamiltonian to get it, where `e` is the energy of the system?

Comment: @codebpr That's right, you solve the Hamiltonian for momentum `py` and `e` is the energy.

Comment: @codebpr The variable `pdy0` is the initial condition that is updated every time you click on the plane `(x, px)` considered in `WhenEvent`.

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks for clarifying. One more doubt, can I export the image as a png file from this interactive plot? Or in other words, how did you get the first image in your answer?

Comment: @codebpr See the update, please!

Comment: @codebpr I hope you generate high-quality images and share the result with the community. I'll move on to placing an additional answer here when I've updated the `ClickPoincarePlot2D` resource function.

Answer (score 7):

There are several problems with your code:

- Hamiltonian construction is not correct (you need to solve for velocities in terms of momenta, not just substitute $x' \to p_x$ and $y' \to p_y$)
- In the linked paper the section is in $(x, p_x)$, while your event is `WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, Sow[{y[t], py[t]}]]` which is wrong

Note, while solving for $p_x$ and $p_y$ I just took one of the branches. Similarly solving for $p_y$ for given $(x, p_x)$ and $y = 0$, I just assume the last solution is positive. Sections looks close, but you need to check my assumptions.

```
k = 1/2 ;
w = 10 ; 
c = 1 ;

lagrangian = -Sqrt[2 k x[t] - x'[t]^2/(2 k x[t]) - y'[t]^2] - w^2/2 ((x[t] - c)^2 + y[t]^2) ;

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[t]] ;
Py = D[lagrangian, y'[t]] ;
hamiltonian = ((Px x'[t] + Py y'[t]) - lagrangian) /. (Solve[{px[t] == Px, py[t] == Py}, {x'[t], y'[t]}] // Last) // FullSimplify ;

equations = {
    x'[t] == +D[hamiltonian, px[t]],
    y'[t] == +D[hamiltonian, py[t]],
    px'[t] == -D[hamiltonian, x[t]], 
    py'[t] == -D[hamiltonian, y[t]]
} // Simplify ;


ClearAll[solution] ;
solution[X_, PX_] := Reap@NDSolve[
        Flatten[
            {
                equations, 
                {x[0] == X, px[0] == PX, y[0] == 0, py[0] == initial[X, PX]},
                WhenEvent[y[t] == 0 && y'[t] > 0, Sow[{x[t], px[t]}]]
            }
        ],
        {},
        {t, 0.0, T},
        MaxSteps -> Infinity
] ;

T = 2000.0 ;

energy = 15.0 ;
constraint = (py /. Solve[energy == hamiltonian /. {x[t] -> x, px[t] -> px, y[t] -> 0, py[t] -> py}, py]) // Last ;
ClearAll[initial] ;
initial[x_?NumericQ, px_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[constraint]
ListPlot[Table[solution[X, 0.0] // Last // First, {X, 0.5, 1.5, 0.01}], PlotRange->All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Tiny], Black}], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize->Large, GridLines->None]

energy = 40.0 ;
constraint = (py /. Solve[energy == hamiltonian /. {x[t] -> x, px[t] -> px, y[t] -> 0, py[t] -> py}, py]) // Last ;
ClearAll[initial] ;
initial[x_?NumericQ, px_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[constraint]
ListPlot[Table[solution[X, 0.0] // Last // First, {X, 0.2, 1.5, 0.01}], PlotRange->All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Tiny], Black}], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize->Large, GridLines->None]

energy = 49.5 ;
constraint = (py /. Solve[energy == hamiltonian /. {x[t] -> x, px[t] -> px, y[t] -> 0, py[t] -> py}, py]) // Last ;
ClearAll[initial] ;
initial[x_?NumericQ, px_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[constraint]
ListPlot[Table[solution[X, 0.0] // Last // First, {X, 0.2, 1.5, 0.01}], PlotRange->All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[Tiny], Black}], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize->Large, GridLines->None]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is a nice solution (+1). Maybe it could be better to variate `y[0]` as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, right, it seems they've used $y=0.1$ (see page 5)

Comment: In general case it could be better to use random values as in my answer.

Comment: @I.M. Thank you for rectifying my conceptual error!

Comment: @AlexTrounev, could you explain about using random being beneficial? From my understanding with random initials you hit more islands?

Comment: @I.M. Yes it is, we need to cover some domain of initial data. The best way is to take some set of random points.

Comment: @I.M. just a small doubt, suppose I am making the Poincare section for the first time, how do I choose my range for `X`? for example you have chosen it to be `{X, 0.5, 1.5, 0.01}` similar to that in the figure. What if I am working on a system for which I don't know which range to choose? I am asking this since sometimes when I choose a random range, I get a lot of `NDSolve` errors like system being too stiff etc.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by I.M. the Hamiltonian could be derive with using Legendre transformation - see for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316884/what-is-the-relation-between-the-hamiltonian-and-lagrangian-in-gr-to-newtonian-m#:%7E:text=The%20typical%20way%20of%20deriving%20the%20Hamiltonian%20from,H%20%3D%20p%CE%BC%CB%99x%CE%BC%20%E2%88%92%20L%20%3D%201%202g%CE%BC%CE%BDp%CE%BCp%CE%BD.). Therefore we have

```
k = 1/2;
w = 10;
c = 1;

lagrangian = -Sqrt[2  k  x[t] - x'[t]^2/(2  k  x[t]) - y'[t]^2] - 
   w^2/2  ((x[t] - c)^2 + y[t]^2);

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[t]];
Py = D[lagrangian, y'[t]];
hamiltonian = ((Px  x'[t] + Py  y'[t]) - 
     lagrangian) /. (Solve[{px[t] == Px, py[t] == Py}, {x'[t], 
       y'[t]}] // First) /. {x[t] -> x, px[t] -> px, y[t] -> y, 
   py[t] -> py}
```

Last expression we use in two forms

```
h[x_, px_, y_, py_] := (
   py^2 x)/((1 + py^2 + px^2 x) Sqrt[
    x - (py^2 x)/(1 + py^2 + px^2 x) - (px^2 x^2)/(
     1 + py^2 + px^2 x)]) + (
   px^2 x^2)/((1 + py^2 + px^2 x) Sqrt[
    x - (py^2 x)/(1 + py^2 + px^2 x) - (px^2 x^2)/(
     1 + py^2 + px^2 x)]) + Sqrt[
   x - (py^2 x)/(1 + py^2 + px^2 x) - (px^2 x^2)/(
    1 + py^2 + px^2 x)] + 50  ((-1 + x)^2 + y^2);

H0[{x_, px_, y_, py_}] := (
   py^2 x)/((1 + py^2 + px^2 x) Sqrt[
    x - (py^2 x)/(1 + py^2 + px^2 x) - (px^2 x^2)/(
     1 + py^2 + px^2 x)]) + (
   px^2 x^2)/((1 + py^2 + px^2 x) Sqrt[
    x - (py^2 x)/(1 + py^2 + px^2 x) - (px^2 x^2)/(
     1 + py^2 + px^2 x)]) + Sqrt[
   x - (py^2 x)/(1 + py^2 + px^2 x) - (px^2 x^2)/(
    1 + py^2 + px^2 x)] + 50  ((-1 + x)^2 + y^2);
```

In this case we can generate initial values using `NMiimize` as follows

```
inivalues[E0_, n_, xmin_, xmax_] := 
  Module[{X, x, px, PX, y, P, py, Y}, 
   x = RandomReal[{xmin, xmax}, n];
   PX = Table[0, {n}]; Y = Table[0, {n}]; P = Table[0, {n}];
   Do[{PX[[i]], P[[i]], Y[[i]]} = {px, py, y} /. 
       NMinimize[(h[x[[i]], px, y, py] - E0)^2, {px, py, 
          y}][[2]];, {i, n}]; Transpose[{x, PX, Y, P}]];
```

For `E0=15` we have
iniv = inivalues[15, 100, .5, 1.5];

Map[H0, iniv]

```
(*Out[]= {15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., \
15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., \
15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., \
15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., \
15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., \
15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., \
15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., 15., \
15., 15., 15., 15.}*)
```

Therefore the energy is saved for every run. Last portion of code is same as in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290227/the-poincar%C3%A9-sections-of-yang-mills-higgs-system/290235#290235), also we use `{x[t],px[t]}` for visualization and `y[t] == 0 && y'[t] > 0` for events detection as in a paper linked

```
{a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[h[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], px[t]], 
  D[h[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], 
   py[t]], -D[h[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], x[t]], -D[
    h[x[t], px[t], y[t], py[t]], y[t]]}; abcd = {x'[t] == a1, 
  px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, py'[t] == d1};
psect[{x0_, px0_, y0_, py0_}] := 
 Reap[NDSolve[{abcd, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, px[0] == px0, 
     py[0] == py0, 
     WhenEvent[y[t] == 0 && y'[t] > 0, Sow[{x[t], px[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 
     0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]][[-1, 1]]
```

Finally we have

```
abcdata = Map[psect, iniv];

ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Large, Background -> Black, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

For `E0=40` we have picture
[image: Figure 2]

And for `E0=49.6`
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you again for providing such an elaborate solution :)  I hope the problem with https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/
also gets rectified soon, it is not working for any MMA version, as of now.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The resource function [["ClickPoincarePlot2D"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/) is also working now, thanks to the new update.

I have also used the `ScalarPureFunction` by @[E. Chan-López](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53427/e-chan-l%C3%B3pez) presented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/299979/78049) to simplify my Hamiltonian into a scalar function form.

```
ScalarPureFunction[f_, 
    argvars_?
     VectorQ] /; (SameQ[Length[Variables[Level[f, {-1}]]], 
      Length[Flatten[argvars]]] && Length[argvars] > 1) := 
  Module[{positions, heldPart, replacements}, 
   positions = MapIndexed[List, argvars, {-1}];
   heldPart = 
    MapThread[
     Function[
      HoldForm[Part][\[FormalP], 
       Apply[Sequence, Part[SlotSequence@1, 2, All]]]], {positions}];
   replacements = Thread[argvars -> heldPart];
   ReleaseHold[
    Fold[Function[#, #2] &, {\[FormalP]}, {f /. replacements}]]];

ScalarPureFunction[f_][argvars_?VectorQ] := 
  ScalarPureFunction[f, argvars];

k = 1/2;
w = 10;
c = 1;

lagrangian = -Sqrt[2  k  x[t] - x'[t]^2/(2  k  x[t]) - y'[t]^2] - 
   w^2/2  ((x[t] - c)^2 + y[t]^2);

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[t]];
Py = D[lagrangian, y'[t]];
hamiltonian = ((Px  x'[t] + Py  y'[t]) - 
      lagrangian) /. (Solve[{px[t] == Px, py[t] == Py}, {x'[t], 
        y'[t]}] // Last) // FullSimplify;

H := ScalarPureFunction[
  hamiltonian /. {x[t] -> x, px[t] -> px, y[t] -> y, py[t] -> py}, {x,
    px, y, py}]

{a1, b1, c1, d1} = {D[hamiltonian, px[t]], 
  D[hamiltonian, 
   py[t]], -D[hamiltonian, x[t]], -D[hamiltonian, 
    y[t]]}; hameqns = {x'[t] == a1, px'[t] == c1, y'[t] == b1, 
  py'[t] == d1};

cross = y[t]; recover = {x[t], px[t]};
```

**E=15**

```
ResourceFunction[
          "ClickPoincarePlot2D"][hameqns, H, 15, t, 6000, cross, recover,
        {PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1], AspectRatio -> 1, 
          PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, Automatic}, PlotHighlighting -> None}]
```

[image: E-15]

**E=40**

```
ResourceFunction
  "ClickPoincarePlot2D"][hameqns, H, 40, t, 6000, cross, recover,
{PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1], AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, Automatic}, PlotHighlighting -> None}]
```

[image: E-40]

**E=49.5**

```
ResourceFunction
      "ClickPoincarePlot2D"][hameqns, H, 49.5, t, 6000, cross, recover,
    {PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1], AspectRatio -> 1, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, Automatic}, PlotHighlighting -> None}]
```

[image: E-49.5]