# Converting to a scalar pure function without getting the warning messages

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, core-language

I am using [this](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/) from the function repository for which I need to convert one of my functions into a unique form. A simple example is like this:

Suppose I have,

```
H[px_, py_, x_, y_] := 1/2 (px^2 + py^2) + (x^2 + y^2) + 1/2 x^2 y^2
```

and I need to convert this into a pure function with a particular form:

```
H := Function[{S}, 1/2 (S[[2]]^2 + S[[4]]^2) + S[[1]]^2 + S[[3]]^2 + 1/2 S[[1]]^2 S[[3]]^2]
```

The simple way I do this is by using,

```
H[px, py, x, y] /. x -> S[[1]] /. px -> S[[2]] /. y -> S[[3]] /. py -> S[[4]]
```

But this approach gives me warning messages. Is there a more elegant way by which I can automate the entire process?

Comment: `hPure = H[#[[2]], #[[4]], #[[1]], #[[3]]] &` ?

Comment: Or simply turn off the warning messages: `hPure = H[px, py, x, y] /. {x -> S[[1]], px -> S[[2]], y -> S[[3]], py -> S[[4]]} // Quiet`. It's not entirely clear what the actual final form should be. Which function from the WFR are you using?

Comment: @Domen Actually `H` stands for hamiltonian. I am dealing with a system with magnetic field, so every time I change the value of the field, my hamiltonian changes, now if I wish to use the hamiltonian that I calculated to generate a Poincare section using [this](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/) resource function, I have to alter it's form. It's a repetitive process so manually doing it every time is not so efficient, that's why I was searching for some automation.

Comment: But there is no magnetic field in the Hamiltonian you provided. How are you changing it? You can just do `hMagnetic[b_] := Function[{S}, 1/2 (S[[2]]^2 + S[[4]]^2 + S[[1]]^2 + S[[3]]^2) + 2*S[[1]]^2 S[[3]] + b S[[3]]]`, and then call `ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"][..., hMagnetic[0.1], ...]`. Please provide more concrete example of what you are using, otherwise, it seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The warning message that I am getting with a clean kernel is `"Part specification S[[1]] is longer than depth of object"` which makes sense since `S` is undefined.

Comment: @Domen, it's not. I said, "Every time I change the value of the field, my Hamiltonian changes". I never said, "field is incorporated in the Hamiltonian, which retains its structure." Magnetic field altering the system implies, that for each magnetic field, I have a different Hamiltonian, for which one of the simplest examples I have provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimal method to get your code to work, is to just define your `H` as:

```
H[{px_, py_, x_, y_}] := 1/2 (px^2 + py^2) + (x^2 + y^2) + 1/2 x^2 y^2
```

and then call:

```
ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"][{eq1, ...}, H[#]&, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks! This would be the minimal way to save my time.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`):

```
pureH = Function[S, H[px, py, x, y] // Evaluate] /. x :> S[[1]] /. px :> S[[2]] /. 
  y :> S[[3]] /. py :> S[[4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can make a scalar version of the [TensorPureFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TensorPureFunction/) function as follows:

```
ScalarPureFunction[f_, 
    argvars_?
     VectorQ] /; (SameQ[Length[Variables[Level[f, {-1}]]], 
      Length[Flatten[argvars]]] && Length[argvars] > 1) := Module[
    {positions, heldPart, replacements},
    positions = MapIndexed[List, argvars, {-1}];
    heldPart = MapThread[
            Function[
                
      HoldForm[Part][\[FormalP], 
       Apply[Sequence, Part[SlotSequence @ 1, 2, All]]]
            ],
            {positions}
        ];
    replacements = Thread[argvars -> heldPart];
    ReleaseHold[
    Fold[Function[#, #2] &, {\[FormalP]}, {f /. replacements}]]
   ];

ScalarPureFunction[f_][argvars_?VectorQ] := ScalarPureFunction[f, argvars];
```

Testing `ScalarPureFunction`:

```
ScalarPureFunction[1/2  (px^2 + py^2 + x^2 + y^2) + 1/2  x^2  y^2, {x, px, y, py}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know the jargon either. So even functions can be scalar or tensor.

Comment: @codebpr This is what we can submit together to the repository :)

Comment: @codebpr I'm going to document it and co-author it with you and another colleague. Next, I'll send something else with Alex.

Comment: I have also edited the one. you wish to use, let me post that too, as an answer to that question.

Comment: Also, please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300022/78049) related question I asked today based on your first interactive algorithm. I think it would be an excellent addition to your resource function if you also enable the user to pick a suitable `Method` for `NDSolve` as you can see that sensitive systems with small positive maximal Lyapunov exponent show better results in some than others.

Comment: @codebpr In fact, not only the method in `NDSolve`, I also need to include an argument for the events in `WhenEvent`, since not all events are simple conditions like in the examples I handle. This will take some time to do in great detail, as I need to test these changes to make the documentation more instructive. I'll go in steps, as I would like to submit this resource function first before submitting an update to `ClickPoincarePlot2D`.

Comment: @codebpr There are other things I want to add, but it seems like a lot for a resource function. Currently, I am writing a project to carry out a postdoctoral position in my country and this will make my progress in updating ClickPoincarePlot2D slow, but it is certain that I will finish it. Perhaps, and with good active collaboration, this expanded work will lead to a publication, or also to build a Paclet that serves as a laboratory for the analysis of Poincaré sections.

Comment: Same for me, I am also in the process of writing my PhD thesis. If you don't mind, can you share your email so that we can communicate efficiently on this subject with elaborate discussions so that we may be able to achieve something similar to what Professor [Leo C. Stein](https://duetosymmetry.com/) of the University of Mississippi and his team did in [JavaScript](https://duetosymmetry.com/tool/poincare-section-clicker-toy/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151868/discussion-between-e-chan-lopez-and-codebpr).

Comment: @codebpr The `ScalarPureFunction` has been submitted to the repository.

Comment: Congratulations! I hope it will be published soon :)

Comment: @codebpr You are a co-author (Bhaskar Shukla) and so is Alex. I'll let you know as soon as it's published. ;)

Comment: Great news to start the day with! Thank you :)

Comment: @codebpr The work is done! [ScalarPureFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ScalarPureFunction/?i=ScalarPureFunction&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch)

Comment: Wow! Many congratulations to you and all other collaborators :)

Comment: @codebpr Congratulations to you too! We already have a first collaboration. Let's go for more.

Comment: Yes, definitely! I am also working on improving the Poincare section function.

Comment: @codebpr I'm trying to move forward with updating that function (Poincare), but I'm wondering which topic to address first. We must add events to the arguments so that we can address more complicated systems in that sense, such as systems that include pendulums. With so many arguments, we approach the need to create an interface like that of Leo C. Stein. I have stopped a little because I advanced on a function for Hamilton equations that includes an analysis of the regularity of Lagrangians. The idea is that we can build the Dynamic Analysis Paclet.