# Poincaré Section from action

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, physics

I am given a perturbative action $$\frac{S}{\mathcal{T}}=\int dt\sum _{n=0,1} (\dot{c_n}{}^2-c_n^2 \omega _n^2)+7.11 c_0^3+35.3 c_0 c_1^2+4.66 c_0 \dot{c_0}{}^2+1.32 c_0 \dot{c_1}{}^2-7.57 \dot{c_0} c_1 \dot{c_1}$$ where $\omega _0^2=-1.4$ and $\omega _1^2=7.57$, by solving the time evolution based on the above action, we can examine if the system exhibits chaos or not by constructing a Poincaré Section.

How shall I construct such Poincaré Sections defined by $c_1( t)=0$ and $\dot{c_1} (t)>0$ for bound orbits with energy `E=9.28 X 10^(-6)` and `0<t<8000` ?

I have read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/poincare-section-of-an-hamiltonian) but don't understand how to apply it to my problem. The related paper from which, I am trying to reproduce the results is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06756.pdf)(specifically on page 5, figure 4).

Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Comment: For reference: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/PoincareSections.html

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will give it another go. I understand the previous attempt had some flaws.

Let us obtain the equations of motion again.

```
\[Omega]sq[0] = -1.4; \[Omega]sq[1] = 7.57;
lagrangian = 
  Sum[c[n]'[t]^2 - c[n][t]^2 \[Omega]sq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + 
   7.11 c[0][t]^3 + 35.3 c[0][t] c[1][t]^2 + 
   4.66 c[0][t] c[0]'[t]^2 + 1.32 c[0][t] c[1]'[t]^2 - 
   7.57 c[0]'[t] c[1][t] c[1]'[t];
eulerLagrange[lagrangian_, vars_, dvars_] :=
    Thread[(Table[
            D[D[lagrangian, dvar], t],
            {dvar, dvars}
            ] -
        Table[
            D[lagrangian, var],
            {var, vars}
            ]) == ConstantArray[0, Length@vars]];
equationsOfMotion = 
 eulerLagrange[lagrangian, {c[0][t], c[1][t]}, {c[0]'[t], c[1]'[t]}]
```

And the key is that we have to simultaneously solve both equations of motion. As we do this we collect the values of $c_0, \dot{c}_0$ every time $c_1(t)=0$.

```
sol = Table[Block[{a, b, \[Chi], d},
        {a, b, \[Chi], d} = {-0.10, c\[Prime], -0.002, 0.002};
        Reap[NDSolve[
            {Splice[equationsOfMotion],
            c[0][0] == a, c[0]'[0] == b, c[1][0] == \[Chi], c[1]'[0] == d,
            WhenEvent[c[1][t] == 0,
                    Sow[{c[0][t], c[0]'[t]}]]},
            {c[0][t], c[1][t]},
            {t, 0, 8000}
            ]
            ]
    ], {c\[Prime], -0.1, 0.1, 0.01}];
```

Now we get better looking results:

```
ListPlot[
        Table[Flatten[sol[[i]][[2]], 1], {i, Length@sol}],
        PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    ]
```

[image]

Still, room for improvement. In particular I don't know what the initial conditions for the $c_1$ field are. Maybe if we could figure those out the plot would be closer to the one in the paper?

Comment: Thank you for this illuminating answer! It definitely helped me get started. I will try to use this code in my work and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Let me know if you get better pictures!

Comment: thank you once again. I have one question. How to view the closeup of the above plot, as given in the paper, indicating chaos?

Comment: Also, instead of giving the initial conditions, they have provided the energy of orbits as ``E=9.28*10^(-6)``. How to include that in the code?

Comment: To zoom in just change the plot range. For the energy you'll have to get a formula that expresses energy in terms of the fields then solve for the fields numerically.