Regarding Poincare section
I got a code from Mathematica to plot the Poincare section and in this code, so many initial conditions are taken at a time. The link and the code is given below.
link
abc = {Derivative[1][x][t] == 3/4 Cos[y[t]] + Sin[z[t]], 
  Derivative[1][y][t] == Cos[z[t]] + Sin[x[t]], 
  Derivative[1][z][t] == Cos[x[t]] + 3/4 Sin[y[t]]};

psect[{x0_, y0_, z0_}] := 
Reap[NDSolve[{abc, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0, 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, Sow[{x[t], z[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]][[-1, 1]]

abcdata = 
 Mod[Map[psect, {{4.267682454609692, 0, 
     0.9952906114885919}, {1.6790790859443243, 0, 
     2.1257099470901704}, {2.9189523719753327, 0, 
     4.939152797323216}, {3.1528896559036776, 0, 
     4.926744120488727}, {0.9829282640373566, 0, 
     1.7074633238173198}, {0.4090394012299985, 0, 
     4.170087631574883}, {6.090600411133905, 0, 
     2.3736566160602277}, {6.261716134007686, 0, 
     1.4987884558838156}, {1.005126683795467, 0, 
     1.3745418575363608}, {1.5880780704325377, 0, 
     1.3039536044289253}, {3.622408133554125, 0, 
     2.289597511313432}, {0.030948690635763183, 0, 
     4.306922133429981}, {5.906038850342371, 0, 5.000045498132029}}],
   2 \[Pi]];

ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Medium]


and got the Poincare section which is given below:

My question is how to find out all these possible initial conditions for a given system?

There are several posts on this regards, see for example https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/poincare-section-of-a-hamiltonian?rq=1
